# How can I use a while loop that stores user input up until 5 as a count

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {
  public static void main(String[] args ){


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //My String Array List holding all of the emotions aslong with a for loop for I can get 
    //All the words to print to the screen 
    String emotion [] = new String [10];
    emotion [0] = "Happy";
    emotion [1] = "Sad";
    emotion [2] = "Vibing";
    emotion [3] = "Trapping";  
    emotion [4] = "Ambationz";
    emotion [5] = "Anxious";
    emotion [6] = "Positive";
    emotion [7] = "Scared"; 
    emotion [8] = "Worried"; 
    emotion [9] = "Focused";


    System.out.println(" Have You ever felt an emotion and didnt know the song to put on at the moment? \n Well Just type in your feeling and this super ADVANCED Java Program will determine your song matching with your emotion");
    //Used a  for loop for I can print out my string Array
      for(int i = 0; i <  emotion.length; i++){
      System.out.println(emotion[i]);
    }
     System.out.println(" How are you feeling please use one of the words printed above");
    String n = ""; 
     // used a while loop for it can    
    while(songfinder(n).equals("Not Available Try Again")){
     n = scan.nextLine();
    songfinder(n);
     System.out.println(songfinder(n));

    }
    System.out.println(" Now Copy and paste the link above asdinto a Web broswer and enjoy the musica");

}
  //My Method for finding the user input and matching it with their song 
   public static String songfinder( String w ) 
    {


      if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Happy"))
        return "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbZSe6N_BXs";

      if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Sad"))
       return " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgN-vvVVxMA"; 

      if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Vibing"))
        return "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2qG5uwDCW4";

      if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Trapping"))
        return "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuEx6lNHZjM";

       if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Ambationz"))
         return "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQZqPi1aHNo";

       if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Positive"))
       return "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4UqMyldS7Q";

       if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Scared"))
         return"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtdsvvMjJ0I";

       if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Worried"))
       return "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3HQMbQAWRc";

       if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Focused"))
         return"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ";

         return "Not Available Try Again";


      }
}
```

What I want to do is a while loop that keeps asking would you like to try again and basically starts my whole code over again

Comment: use do-while loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    ...
    System.out.println("Do you want to try again (y/n)?");
} while (scan.nextLine().equals("y"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an **excellent** time to learn about enumerated types (enums). Using an `enum` we can associate a song, an emotion and get the list without repeating the terms and without assorted `if` ladders. For example,

```
public enum Emotions {
    Happy("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbZSe6N_BXs"), //
    Sad("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgN-vvVVxMA"), //
    Vibing("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2qG5uwDCW4"), //
    Trapping("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuEx6lNHZjM"), //
    Ambationz("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQZqPi1aHNo"), //
    Anxious("Not Available Try Again"), //
    Positive("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4UqMyldS7Q"), //
    Scared("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtdsvvMjJ0I"), //
    Worried("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3HQMbQAWRc"), //
    Focused("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ");
    Emotions(String songUrl) {
        this.songUrl = songUrl;
    }

    public static Emotions fromName(String name) {
        for (Emotions e : values()) {
            if (e.name().equals(name)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return songUrl;
    }

    private String songUrl;
}
```

And then your `main` method can be simplified to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Have You ever felt an emotion and didnt know the song to put on at the moment?");
    System.out.println(" Well Just type in your feeling and this super ADVANCED Java Program "
            + "will determine your song matching with your emotion");
    for (int i = 0; i < Emotions.values().length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Emotions.values()[i].name());
    }
    System.out.println("How are you feeling please use one of the words printed above");
    while (true) {
        String n = scan.nextLine();
        Emotions e = Emotions.fromName(n);
        if (e == null) {
            System.out.println("Not Available Try Again");
        } else {
            System.out.println(e.getUrl());
            System.out.println("Now Copy and paste the link above asdinto a Web broswer and enjoy the musica");
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to try again (y/n)?");
        String again = scan.nextLine();
        if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I left all the comments in since this is a school project and I had to have some minimum requirements therefore me having a String Array instead of me having an enum